# SQL. How could i set data unavailable depending of its value and update ir if used? // Restaurant system simulation

Tags: sql, architecture

Im new in SQL and im building a database for testing and learn.

my example is from a restaurant where there are 5 tables: Customer/Table/Order/Sale/dishes

with these columns:

- `CUSTOMER` : customerID, TableID.
- `TABLE`: TableID, OrderID, available(boolean)
- `Order`: FoodID
- `Sale`: OrderID/TotalPrice/customerID/TableID
- `dishes`: foodID/Price

What I want to do is:

1. A table with `SALE` unliquidated can not be assigned to a new client.
2. A sale can not be liquidated if no order.
3. The customer can not ask for dishes that do not exist in table dishes .
4. All orders and sales must be settled the same day as the customer visit .

How could I do that?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Darwin von Corax came up with a complete solution to the problem. You can see his work in the answers and feel free to join in the Chat.

Comment: what you have tried so far? where is data? which dbms are you using? - please come here with some lessons...

Comment: Is the schema predefined for you, or do you have freedom to change the table definitions? Are you required to use a particular database, or are you free to choose? (If you're teaching yourself, I suggest PostgreSQL as the most powerful and standard-compliant.)

Comment: My personal preference is to end table names with S, because a table stores data about several orders, customers etc.

Comment: i´m  free to change the tables and i´m using db2 (ibm)

Comment: Working out a solution now. Was this problem set for you, or did you come up with it on your own?

Comment: i put the problem from my own. i was thinking aboutn a stored procedure where:
 if "available" = true then
insert into clients (id, idtable) values (x,y)
end if

Im new in stored procedures so im not sure if it the best option for this.

What do you think?

Comment: Also a stored procedure for closing the order when the "client" pay the check, something like

update "available" = true where idtable =(y);

Comment: I've come up with a slightly different schema (DISHES, TABLES, ORDERS, ORDER_ITEMS) which assumes you don't track customers across multiple visits. Some of what you want to do can be done with foreign key constraints and the rest with stored procedures. Once I have something I like I'll post it as an answer and then we can discuss it in chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I've got so far.
The tables:

```
                                Table "public.orders"
     Column      |     Type     |                      Modifiers                      
-----------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer      | not null default nextval('orders_id_seq'::regclass)
 discount        | numeric(5,2) | 
 tax             | numeric(5,2) | 
 tip             | numeric(5,2) | 
 amount_tendered | numeric(6,2) | 
 closed          | boolean      | default false
 party_size      | integer      | 
Indexes:
    "order_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "order_items" CONSTRAINT "order_item_fk" FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(id)
    TABLE "tables" CONSTRAINT "table_order_fk" FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(id)

                           Table "public.tables"
  Column   |  Type   |                      Modifiers                      
-----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer | not null default nextval('tables_id_seq'::regclass)
 places    | integer | 
 available | boolean | 
 order_id  | integer | 
Indexes:
    "table_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "fki_table_order_fk" btree (order_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "table_order_fk" FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(id)

                             Table "public.order_items"
  Column   |  Type   |                           Modifiers                           
-----------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 order_id  | integer | not null
 item_id   | integer | not null default nextval('order_items_item_id_seq'::regclass)
 dish_id   | integer | 
 delivered | boolean | 
Indexes:
    "ord_item_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (order_id, item_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "order_item_fk" FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(id)
    "orditem_dish_fk" FOREIGN KEY (dish_id) REFERENCES dishes(id)

                                    Table "public.dishes"
   Column    |          Type           |                      Modifiers                      
-------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                 | not null default nextval('dishes_id_seq'::regclass)
 price       | numeric(5,2)            | 
 description | character varying(1024) | 
Indexes:
    "dish_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "order_items" CONSTRAINT "orditem_dish_fk" FOREIGN KEY (dish_id) REFERENCES dishes(id)
```

Also I have two functions:

```
-- Function: seat_party(integer, integer)

-- DROP FUNCTION seat_party(integer, integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION seat_party(party_size integer DEFAULT 1, preferred_table integer DEFAULT 1)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    assigned_table  tables.id%TYPE  := NULL;
    new_order   orders.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    IF ((preferred_table IS NOT NULL) AND (table_is_available(preferred_table, party_size))) THEN
        assigned_table := preferred_table;
    END IF;
    IF (assigned_table IS NULL) THEN
        SELECT INTO assigned_table
            tables.id
            FROM tables
            WHERE order_id IS NULL
              AND places >= party_size
            LIMIT 1;
    END IF;
    IF (assigned_table IS NOT NULL) THEN
        INSERT INTO orders (party_size)
            VALUES (party_size)
            RETURNING id AS new_order;
        UPDATE tables
            SET order_id = new_order
            WHERE tables.id = assigned_table;
        RETURN assigned_table;
        
    ELSE
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION seat_party(integer, integer)
  OWNER TO dave;
```

and

```
-- Function: table_is_available(integer, integer)

-- DROP FUNCTION table_is_available(integer, integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_is_available(table_id integer, party_size integer)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    ord_id  tables.order_id%TYPE;
    places  tables.places%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO ord_id, places
        tables.order_id
        FROM tables
        WHERE tables.id = table_id;
    RETURN ((avail IS NULL) AND (places >= party_size));
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION table_is_available(integer, integer)
  OWNER TO dave;
```

To complete the solution you will need procedures to take an order, serve an order, pay a bill, and close the day's business. I've created a chat for anyone who wants to question my reasoning or to discuss modifications or extensions: [Extended discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26806424#26806424)

Comment: I just hope I did the chat thing right; it's the first one I've tried to do manually.

Comment: I can´t believe you actually wrote that just for help. Thanks a lot man!
im thinking about changing the question to something more related to a restaurant so if anyone there looking for some complete advise could get in here.

Comment: I needed the exercise. ;)